# I'm adding nodes on top of a parent node and then attempting to run the layout

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

As the title says, I'm retrieving nodes and edges from the server then adding them with the same position as the parent node ({ data, position: { x: parentX, y: parentY }}) and then attempting to layout({ name }).run(). The idea was that the animation would be less visually disrupting if the new nodes seemed to grow from the parent node but that's not what's happening. It seems like the nodes are being added to the same position as the parent and get stuck there even after I run the layout. Everything is fine if I don't add a position but when the layout runs you can see it grab the nodes from the top left-hand corner.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The following Gist contains the command I'm using as well as the function I'm using to create nodes and edges.

https://gist.github.com/afulkerson-semanticarts/baac3f4820f468fc6930e8aebad83446

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] here, preferably in the form of a Stack Snippet.

Comment: If you need help with creating a minimal reproducible example, just let us know. We can help you with that. The thing is, we can't guess your implementation. For an accurate answer we need a precise question.

Comment: Help would help. I'm not sure how I didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. I provided code examples in a Gist and attempted to describe the problem. It looks like you guys want code _in_ the comment but when I tried pasting my code there was too much for a comment.